# DOORS DXL compare two strings; partial matches

Tags: string, string-matching, partial, ibm-doors

I need to compare two text strings for partial, potentially multiple matches.  I've been using the matches dxl function and it works great for simple matches, but is failing for more complex strings.

Ex:
str1 = "[SuRS_39] [SuRS_161] [SuRS_162]"
str2 = "This requirement is covered at subsystem level by : [SuRS_39], [SuRS_161], [SuRS_162]"

if (matches(str1, str2), do...

I want to see if [SuRS_39] or [SuRS_161] or [SuRS_162] from str1 is contained in str2 and if so then return true.

I'm using matches(b,a) in DOORS DXL. I good enough at coding to be able to modify existing scripts, but not really from scratch so I'm unable to figure this one out.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use regular expressions for this, if I understand your task correctly.
The following regex matches to TRUE if the string to be compared contains at least one of [SuRS_39], …161… or …163…, including the square brackets.

```
Regexp matchesSuRS = regexp2 "\\[SuRS_39]|\\[SuRS_161]|\\[SuRS_162]"

string  str2 = "This requirement is covered at subsystem level by : [SuRS_39], [SuRS_161], [SuRS_162]"

if (matchesSuRS str2) {
    print "matches, do ..."
} else {
    print "nope"
}
```

Comment: Hi MIke - thanks for the response.  I'll go check it out.